# D3 get attributes from element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying some basic d3 and i have been trying to get the attributes of each of the `rect` using d3 but I am not able to get anything.

[image: Console Screen]

When i try `d3.selectAll("rect")`, I get

[image: result]

How do can i access attributes of `rect` by using something like `d3.selectAll("rect").select("part1").attr(...)` or something similar? I want to access different attributes of all `rect`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can get any attribute of an element using a **getter**:

```
d3.select(foo).attr("bar")
```

Which is basically the `attr()` function with just one argument.

Here is a demo. There are two classes of rectangles, `part1` and `part2`. I'm selecting all `part1` rectangles and getting their x positions:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var rects = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(14))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "teal")
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("x", d => 10 + 12 * d)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("class", d => d % 2 === 0 ? "part1" : "part2");

d3.selectAll(".part1").each(function(d,i) {
  console.log("The x position of the rect #" + i + " is " + d3.select(this).attr("x"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have two more questions from the code above.
1. `.attr("x", d => 10 + 12 * d) ` what does `d => 10 + 12 * d` mean?
2. `d3.select(this).attr("x")` does `this` mean the element that is passed in because of `function(d,i)`?

Comment: `this` is the DOM element, regardless `d` or `i`. And that math is just to spread the rects in the SVG (`d` goes from 0 to 13).

Comment: How would I store the x values in an array and/or bind them back to the rectangles for future use?

Comment: Please ask this as a new question.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272928/get-attributes-of-existing-svg-elements-and-bind-as-data-with-d3-js