# Get attributes of existing SVG elements and bind as data with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an existing svg element such as:

```
<svg width="300" height="200">
    <circle cx="50" cy="10" r="5" fill="green"></circle>
    <circle cx="100" cy="20" r="10" fill="green"></circle>
    <circle cx="150" cy="30" r="15" fill="green"></circle>
</svg>
```

I would like to extract the cx values of the circles and bind them as data back to the circles.  I can do it with one:

```
var x = +d3.select('circle').attr('cx');
d3.select('circle').datum(x);
```

However I cannot figure out how to collect all of the cx values into an array and them join them to the circles. (Or perhaps there a more direct way to do this without the data array.)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43646752/5314416) explains how to view all attributes in the console, but doesn't explain how to store them or bind them to DOM elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
d3.selectAll('circle').datum(function() {
  return parseFloat(this.getAttribute('cx'));
});
```

Comment: Yes, perfect.  Along those lines, this also works: `d3.selectAll('circle').datum(function() { return +d3.select(this).attr('cx') });` but this doesn't: `d3.selectAll('circle').datum( () => {+d3.select(this).attr('cx')});` fwiw.

Comment: @jtr13 you cannot use `this` with an arrow function. It should be: `d3.selectAll('circle').datum((d,i,n) => {+d3.select(n[i]).attr('cx')});`

Comment: Aha. Is `this` being phased out or considered bad form?

Comment: No. It's just the basic difference between a regular function and an arrow function. Please read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions